# How can I generate notification icons correctly on Android?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, push-notification, android-notifications

I found a documentation from [OneSignal](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/customize-notification-icons) saying that the icons must be white even, from API 21.

[image: OneSignal documentation]

I was using [Android Asset Studio](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.type=clipart&source.clipart=ac_unit&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_stat_ac_unit) previously. Images are being generated in white.

[image: Android Asset Studio]

[image: Notification icon]

[image: Icons used in the previous version of the app]

Answer (score 1):

your "icon" have a rounded background, so it is also converted to white pixels... your notification icon should contain only image-shape, e.g. logo of app without background - put this image into Assest Studio and you will get proper icon (every non-transparent pixel will be converted to white)

for example: Facebook icon is small "f" letter on blue rounded-corner background - put only "f" icon on transparent background to get proper white icon in Asset Studio (well, in this case it is already white...)

Comment: I updated the description with the image of the icons used in the previous version of the app, which I am using as the main icon of the app too

Comment: so now just remove green background and put into Asset Manager transparent PNG with these three arrows only - these will be converted to white, transparent background will stay transparent and you have your notification icon

Answer (score 0):

As i know, if your app supports Android 2.3 to 2.3.7 (API level 9 to 10), Image Asset Studio generates a gray version of your icon. Later Android versions use the white icon that Image Asset Studio generates.

The way to generate the correct notification icon:

1. Use the `ANDROID ASSET STUDIO`. https://jgilfelt.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html#foreground.type=image&foreground.space.trim=1&foreground.space.pad=-0.05&foreColor=e8eaf6%2C27&crop=1&backgroundShape=none&backColor=e8eaf6%2C100&effects=none&elevate=0
2. Download the icon which you want from the website. You could search icon in goole. It would show a lot of websites whicn could download.